# how to stop screen sharing using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, screensharing

I'm using [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia) to get access to screen sharing. When user clicks a stop button, I want to stop screen sharing.

According to [MediaStream API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_API#stop()), the `stop()` function should be called to stop sharing. But when I do so, I find the Chrome bar `https://xxx is sharing your screen <button>Stop sharing</button>` is still there, although the stream has stopped.

Is there a function that can make Chrome bar disappear?

Answer (score 6):

For as far as i am aware the MediaStream.stop method is deprecated. If you want to stop a MediaStream you should stop and close it's tracks. Thwn doing this the "Chrome bar" you mention will disapear once all tracks bound to the shared screen are stopped. This can be achieved through the following code. "this.screenStream" is the MediaStream object of the shared screen.

```
    var tracks = this.screenStream.getTracks();
    for( var i = 0 ; i < tracks.length ; i++ ) tracks[i].stop();
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

Command-line flag based screen sharing can be stopped using same `MediaStream.stop` or `MediaStreamTracks.stop` method however if you're using [desktopCapture API](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Chrome-Extensions/desktopCapture) ( [demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/desktop-sharing/) ) then there is `cancelChooseDesktopMedia` which can be used like this:

```
function releaseCapturing() {
    // getting desktop-media-id from local-storage
    chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia(parseInt(localStorage['desktop-media-request-id']));
}

function captureDesktop() {
    var desktop_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
        ["screen", "window"], onAccessApproved);

    // storing desktop-media-id in the local-storage
    localStorage.setItem('desktop-media-request-id', desktop_id);
}
```

Comment: I'm using `MediaStream.stop()`, but as I said, the Chrome bar `https://xxx is sharing your screen <button>Stop sharing</button>` is still there after `MediaStream.stop()` is called. I want to remove the Chrome bar. Is this possible?

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing the same issue. Can't seem to get around it

Comment: I have the same and just solved it. You have call stop on every track (video and audio if they exist) of that media stream. If the tracks get replaced/removed due to some further modification or processing down the line, then you may have to store a reference to the tracks before passing the media stream for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use stream.onended

```
stream.onended = () => {
  console.info("ScreenShare has ended");
};
```

or you can listen for ended event

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => {
  //perform your task here
});
```

Comment: while this doesn't answer the initial question, I want to add that the "onended" event needs to be added on the actual video track (of the getDisplayMedia stream) "getVideoTracks()[0].onended = ...". So basically instead of "addEventListener('ended', ...".

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the media stream
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();

// get the media track
const mediaTrack = mediaStream.getTracks()[0];

// stop the media track to stop screen sharing
mediaTrack.stop();
```

In my case, I called MediaStream.getTracks()[0].stop()